# Dividing logs with same base

Tags: logarithms

**Problem**

$\dfrac{\log125}{\log25} = 1.5$

From my understanding, if two logs have the same base in a division, then the constants can simply be divided i.e $125/25 = 5$ to result in ${\log5} = 1.5$ but that is not the case as   ${\log5} \neq 1.5$ .

**Correct answer**

Each log can be rewritten to be $\frac{3\log5}{2\log5} = 1.5$ therefore $\frac{3}{2} = 1.5$

I'm unsure why this is correct over the previous method.

**My question**

What was wrong with simply dividing the constants $125/25 = 5$ versus rearranging the logarithm?

Comment: In which basis is $\log 5$ equal to $1.5$?

Comment: Do you understand why it's correct to say that $\log 125=3\log 5$?

Comment: @Bernard It isn't . Sorry if it was not clear in the question as I was unable to perform the 'not equals to' symbol

Comment: The code is `\neq`, as in LaTeX.

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes I understand that you can remove the multiple by converting it to an exponent and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "understanding" is just totally wrong.  It's not true that $\frac{\log a}{\log b}=\log(a/b)$ in general, and indeed this problem is a counterexample.

Comment: The confusion stems from the fact that $log6 - log3 =   \dfrac{\log6}{\log3} = log2$ . I believe you can divide $ \dfrac{\log6}{\log3}$ to result in $ log2$ hence I would have thought you can apply $\dfrac{\loga}{\logb} = log(a/b)$

Comment: No, that's false as well.  $\log 6-\log 3=\log(6/3)=\log 2$ but this is not the same as $\frac{\log 6}{\log 3}$.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I was getting confused with the minus operation and division. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 8):

Dividing logs which have the same base changes the base of the log.

That is $\frac {\log a}{\log b} = \log_b a$

It doesn't matter what base we were using on the left hand side.  It will change the base of the log as above.

$\frac {\log 125}{\log 25} = \log_{25} 125$ and $25^{\frac 32} = 125$