# Is there a transform to divide a log by another log with the same base such that the original logs do not need to be evaluated?

Tags: logarithms

It’s been suggested to me that I can solve for x in $5^x$$^-$$^1$$ = 2$ by converting to log base 10.  I’ve tried converting to base 10 but I arrive at  $x=\frac{\log2}{\log 5}+1$ and am unable to go further without using a calculator.

I’ve also tried to solve for x by first converting to base 5.  The outcome $x=log_5^2+1$ is a little better, but I’d still need to resort to a calculator to solve for x.

Is there a way to do this that I have not considered?  I had a look at [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2833067/dividing-logs-with-same-base) (entitled Dividing logs with same base) but it didn't answer my question.

Comment: Hint: $2 = 10/5$. But yeah, you'll still need a calculator. This number is transcendental.

Comment: "Converting to base $10$" is an awkward thing to write, since the numbers are already in base $10$ and there is no other base given.

Comment: Also, we usually write $\log 2$ rather than $\log^2.$ Unless you mean something different?

Comment: @BrianTung i’m not sure what to do with the hint.  In my original transform, I’ve already converted the Right Hand Side to log base 10.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to me @ThomasAndrews, I meant to write “log base 10”.  I’ve corrected my post.

Comment: @duckegg: I just meant that one can multiply both sides by $5$ to get $5^x = 10$, and then $x = \log_5 10 = \frac{1}{\log_10 5}$. But as I said, that number is transcendental and can't be simplified further. Were you expecting a different form?